# Add target blank to a link in a props in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, hyperlink

I use the [ReadMore](https://github.com/orlyyani/read-more/) plugin to crop articles in a page. The plugin provides a props to redirect to a http link when the "read more" is clicked. But I need to display the link in a new tab. The props receives the link in a string.

I tried several ways to add the target blank attribute to this string before passing it to the props. With no success. Like:

```
http://www.example.com/page-to-see.html target=_"blank"
```

I used it with or without quotes but in any case, the link works but the attribute is skipped.

Is there a way to intercept this and add a target blank later?

I saw in other questions the use of router-link but I don't know how to manipulate the props content in the first place.

Any clue would be warmly welcomed

Edit: adding more code to give a clearer explanation of the problem I try to solve:

**In the template:**

```
<read-more  more-str="read more" :text="dwId.texte" :link="dwId.link" less-str="less" :max-chars="540"></read-more>
```

I get the values from a DB with Axios. The props are specified by the plugin documentation.

The *:link* must be a string and it's what it gets from the DB. It works. But as I explained, I need to open in a new tab.

**Edit: what I tried:**

I try to make a computed property that would add the target blank to a string and use it in the read-more props:

```
computed: {
  target: function() {                 
    return this.dwIds.filter((dwId) => {
        return dwId.link + target="_blank"
    });       
  }, 
}
```

I have two issues here: first , the result is an object and the props requires a string. Furthermore, the way I add the target blank is not correct but I can't find the right syntax yet.

Comment: please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it as a directive, and override parts of the initial element you're passing. Otherwise there is no way to "intercept" it. [Here's](https://github.com/orlyyani/read-more/blob/master/src/ReadMoreComponent.vue) the code to the "component" version that won't do the trick for you.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your hint: could I make a computed which returns the link and the attribute all in a string? Something like: `link: function() {
      return this.dwIds.filter((dwId) => {
        return dwId.link + target="_blank";
      });
    }, ` ?